# Difference between NearestNeighbours and KNearestNeighbour

Tags: python

Is there any different between Nearest Neighbor and KNN or both of them are refereing to the same algorithm?

If both of them are in a different type. what is the different use cases to use n_neighbor to find a correlation using nearest neighbor .

Answer (score 0):

They're the same thing. If I want to refer to it as an abbreviation I use KNN. If I want to say it, I just say nearest neighbor.

KNN is used in supervised machine learning, like classification. Using the common Iris example, I would show you a flower, and you would say "This is an Iris" or "This is not an Iris". We repeat that to build a model, then throw a whole bunch at the model, and we get our results.